# webkit stylewithcss contenteditable not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I'm trying to use contenteditable and styleWithCss.

It doesn't seem to work in webkit.

Anytime I use do an execCommand, it generates a `<b>` rather than the span I expected.

Here's a demo:
http://jsbin.com/izomo/2/edit

Select part of the text, click the bold button, and see the html output.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>It seems like everything is working as intended.</strike> See [Bug 13490](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13490) on WebKit BugZilla.

**EDIT:** Support for styleWithCSS was added to WebKit's source in [changeset 40560](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/40560), on 03 February 2009.

That said, it seems like ever since then, no matter what, `styleWithCSS` is always set to `false`, whereas before the change, style commands were always applied with CSS, as if `styleWithCSS` existed but was always set to `true`.

I even tried rewriting your `document.execCommand` line as follows, in accordance with the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands):

```
document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", true, null);
document.execCommand("bold", false, null);
```

These modified commands still work in Firefox, but not in either Chrome 5 or Safari 5 (both on Windows and installed today).

So, it would seem like this is a WebKit bug.

Comment: That's for stylewithcss false, I'm trying to do stylewithcss true.

Comment: D'oh! Okay. I'll take a dive.

Comment: Same bug as original, but now in opposite direction? I updated my answer after some more research. I think the addition of `styleWithCSS` support was supposed to make it configurable, but it's stuck in its default state, which is `false`. (See [Editor.cpp:940](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/editing/Editor.cpp?rev=61418#L940).)

Comment: Unhappy news, but thank you. I'll accept your answer after the bug gets confirmed.

Comment: Actually your revised command was correct, and that works. Not a bug.

Comment: Odd; wasn't working for me. I wonder if there was something funky going on with JSbin and/or browser cache, because it wasn't working for me... Anyway, glad it worked!

Comment: The third parameter is the command value you want. For `StyleWithCSS`, you need a Boolean third parameter. The second parametere is almost always irrelevant and can be `false`. Hence `document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", false, true);`

Answer (score 10):

I was unable to get this to work with the commands in both the answers here. For those who are still banging their heads with the issue this is how to get it to work.

We can pass three values to execCommand

```
document.execCommand( command, uiElement, value )
```

As Christopher's excellent Answer details the value of "styleWithCSS" is set to false by default
just try:

```
alert(document.queryCommandState("styleWithCss"));
```

To set it to true you need to pass the third argument, "value" as true. Like this:

```
document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", null, true);
```

This works in both Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 2):

```
document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", true, null);
document.execCommand("bold", false, null);
```